# Do Elasticsearch Nodes Keep A Whole Copy of Index?

Tags: elasticsearch, distributed-computing

I've been hunting around on Google and haven't really been able to find a concrete answer to this question; If I have, say, 3 data nodes in an Elasticsearch cluster, does each node contain an entire copy of an index by default?

If one of my nodes goes down will part of the index be missing or will the shards be redistributed over the remaining nodes so an entire copy of the index is always available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have replica set to > 0 (default to 1), you won't loose any data.
Nodes does not contain all data but enough to recover in case do node failure.

If your index has 5 shards and 1 replica for each, which is the default, 10 shards will be spread on the 3 boxes. Note that primary shards and replicas for the same shard won't be allocated on the same node.

Comment: So basically by default Elasticsearch will do its best to keep each shard in at least 2 places when you're running more than one node?

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. Have a look at http://fr.slideshare.net/dadoonet/elasticsearch-devoxx-france-2012-english-version (from slide 120)